# Do I need to standardize my data?

Tags: r, regression, distributions, normalization, standardization

I have the results of mass spectrometry, there are 2500 peaks and in each peak there is the recorded intensity for the samples. My data looks like this:

```
peaks   sample1 ..... sample200
1         0             2
2         0.4           2.1
3         0.7           0
.         .             .
.         .             .
.         .             .
2449      0             1.66
2500      0.2           1.2
```

I want to standardize the sample columns because then all the recorded intensities are on the same scale, but I'm not sure if this is the smartest thing to do. Later on I will build linear models (one for each peak).

Any advice from an expert is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming (perhaps wrongly) that intensity is recorded in some standard way (e.g. like weight being recorded in kilograms).

In this case, the measures are on the same scale now. If you standardize, they will be on different scales, but each sample will have the same mean and sd.

Which do you want? That depends on what you are trying to do. Why do the different samples have different means and variances? Is that something you want to model or something you want to eliminate?

Comment: Thanks for replying. My goal afterwards is to do a linear model to check between the first 100 samples and the remaining 100 samples for hypothesis testing(first 100 are control second 100 are  cases) row by row. What would you recommend in this case?

Comment: That information doesn't help answer the question of standardizing.